Using a Markov Network to match similar names between lists
I have a problem where I am trying to match people between two datasets--meaning it is the dataset but captured during different year ranges. The problem is that the data was manually entered, so there are some variations in equivalent names. For example you might see "Paul Castro" -> "P Castro", or we see misspellings like "Adam Winchester" ->
"Adam Wincheste", and other variations.
The list of names is relatively long and I can't manually go through and fix all of the discrepancies. So I was thinking of using a layered strategy. I thought that perhaps a Markov Network/Constraint Program might work for certain hard matches, but I wanted to see if such a strategy makes sense. The nice thing about the Markov Network is that it lets me find the borderline cases--just over 50% probability--instead of having to check every case.
I am still working on my strategy a bit. I could try and capture exact matches between names before using the Markov network; or I could just have a factor in the Markov net that creates high affinity between names that match exactly. The key thing is to define factors that encourage the type of matches that I want.
I could create some factors based upon different string metrics, where a lower distance has a higher score. The metrics, like the Levensthein metric, could work. I could also have some factors in there for things like the first letter of the first name matches, and the first letter of the last name matches. Some of these more vague factors are meant to encourage matches in the noisiest name discrepancies.
In terms of the algorithm to compute inference on the Markov network, I would probably use some sort of backtracking search with arc consistency (AC-3).
I was just wondering if this idea makes sense. I have not used Markov Networks before, so I don't have a lot of experience there.

Modern ML systems are developed for this problem, which is called Named Entity Recognition, i.e., NER. Pre-trained deep learning based methods probably might perform better.

@patagonicus I was wondering about that. But I thought that named entity recognition was more for identifying entities in unstructured text. Like find the countries listed in this paragraph or such. In this case, it is a direct string matching where there is basically noise that is obscuring the matches in the form of letter transpositions or errors, etc. Would NER systems handle stuff like that?

It is an entity recognition problem at the end. See this from SpaCy forum:  Misspelled named entity extraction. While using Levenshtein distance (LD) or similar approach may not scale. But if your list is small (<100) it may just work with LD-loops.

@patagonicus oh that is good. Yeah, if I can use SpaCy, then that is nice. Thanks for the suggestion, I did not know this option existed. I will give it a shot.
